# BaseURL in Ember CLI application with IE9 support

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

For my Ember CLI application I want to use a baseURL, as described [here](http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#history-api-and-base-url). It works very well for the History API, but for the old Hash API it won't work as expected.

My configuration:

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
    var ENV = {
        environment: environment,
        baseURL: '/base/',
        locationType: 'auto',
        ...
    };

    ...

    return ENV;
}
```

In IE9 i got `localhost:4200/#/base/login` instead of `localhost:4200/base#/login`. Going manually to this page results in a blank (white) page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue apparently: http://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/417

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I used the location: 'auto' property already. Changed my question to include this (Ember CLI calls this property locationType though)

Comment: got that but you can't change that behavior on ie since that's the fallback for not supporting history api.

Comment: I don't want to change the behavior. In the last line I mentioned that IE9 got a wrong link/result. But the link uses the Hash API. So that's fine (Newer browsers do indeed use the History API, those browsers work perfectly). It's just that in IE9 it does not set the base url correctly ==> now: root#/base/path; i want: root/base#/path

Comment: It's a known issue apparently: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/417

Comment: Thx, seems that I got to wait then, till it's fixed. Answer that as an anwer, and you will be rewarded :)

Comment: This still seems to be an unsolved issue.  Here are my findings: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/417#issuecomment-85392044.  Anyone have a workaround?

Comment: Has anyone figured this one out? IE9 works fine if I set the rootURL as in Aaron Renoir's answer below, but then duplicates the base in modern browsers. @JacobvanLingen

Answer (score 6):

I found you have to set the router rootUrl as well as the environment baseUrl.

```
//router.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

let Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,
  rootURL: config.baseURL
});

export default Router;
```